# Python-Kivy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, kivy, kivy-language

I am just getting into coding, so there are probably quite a few coding errors here. I am trying to develop an app that will help with my personal billing. I want this app to first display the text box entry for the invoice# and for(purpose) then proceed to a scrolling page where all the carrier names will be displayed for the user to pick, then the next page (with a similar layout as the first to have a text box for the cost, and a drop-down for local (lists of city names), outcal (same list of city names), Driver (list of driver names), Dispatcher (list of dispatcher names).

In the end, I want all of this information to be stored on a text document so that I could design code to interpret and place it in specified parts of an excel file. Is all this possible in Kivy Exel?

The app opens and we can enter text on the first first screen but crashes as soon as the next button is clicked.  Here is the code and error codes.

Error code for database:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/CJ/Desktop/my app/screens/exel.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "undefined-variable",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined variable 'invoice'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 33,
    "startColumn": 56,
    "endLineNumber": 33,
    "endColumn": 56
}
```

Error code for main.py

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/CJ/Desktop/my app/screens/Screens.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "no-name-in-module",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No name 'ObjectProperty' in module 'kivy.properties'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

I got this no value error for the rest of the names I haven't integrated yet:

```
No value for argument 'carrier' in method call
No value for argument 'carrier' in method call
```

Code:

```
# main.py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,OneLineListItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from exel import DataBase

class TOPRIGHTINVOICE(Screen):
    invoice = ObjectProperty(None)
    For = ObjectProperty(None)

    def next(self):
        db.add_loadinfo(self.invoice.text, self.For.text)

        self.reset()
        sm.current = "CARRIERPAGE"
    
    def reset(self):
        self.invoice.text = "" 
        self.For.text = ""

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "CARRIERPAGE"


class CARRIERPAGE(Screen):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()

        scroll = ScrollView()
        list_view= MDList()
        scroll.add_widget(list_view)

        item1 = OneLineListItem(text='Coyote')
        item2 = OneLineListItem(text='TQL')

        list_view.add_widget(item1)
        list_view.add_widget(item2)

        screen.add_widget(list_view)
     


def MissingInfo():
    pop = Popup(title= 'Missing Information',
                content=Label(text='You are missing information, are you sure you want to continue?'),
                suze_hint=(None,None), size=(400,400))
    pop.open()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("user.txt")

screens = [TOPRIGHTINVOICE(name="main"), CARRIERPAGE(name="CARRIERPAGE")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "main"

class MyScreen(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyScreen().run()
```

```
#my.kv
<TOPRIGHTINVOICE>:
    name: "main"

    invoice: invoice
    purpose: purpose
        

    FloatLayout:
        cols:1

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2


            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
                text: "Invoice #: "
                font_size: dp(20)

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: invoice
                multiline: False
                font_size: dp(20)

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8-0.13}
                text: "For: "
                font_size: dp(20)

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8-0.13}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: purpose
                multiline: False
                font_size: dp(20)

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.25}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: dp(20)
            text: "Next"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.next()


            
            



<CARRIERPAGE>:
    name: "CARRIERPAGE"
    
    Button:
        id:Back
        text: "Back"
        on_release: 
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

```
#exel database
import xlrd, xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
import datetime

class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.loadinfo = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        self.loadinfo = {}

        for line in self.file:
            invoice, purpose, carrier, cost, local, outcal, Driver, Dispatcher = line.strip().split(";")
            self.loadinfo[invoice] = (invoice, purpose, carrier, cost, local, outcal, Driver, Dispatcher)

        self.file.close()

    def top_right(self, invoice, purpose):
        pass

    def add_loadinfo(self, invoice, purpose, carrier, cost, local, outcal, Driver, Dispatcher):
        self.loadinfo[invoice.strip()] = (invoice.strip(), purpose.strip(), carrier.strip(), cost.strip(), local.strip(), outcal.strip(), Driver.strip(), Dispatcher.strip(), DataBase.get_date())
        self.save()

    
    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            for loadinfo in self.loadinfo:
                f.write(loadinfo + ";" + self.loadinfo[invoice][0] + ";" + self.loadinfo[invoice][1] + ";" + self.loadinfo[invoice][2] + "\n")

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]
        

#code to put it into excel

# read_book = xlrd.open_workbook("Invoice.xls", formatting_info=True) #Make Readable Copy
# write_book = copy(read_book) #Make Writeable Copy

# write_sheet1 = write_book.get_sheet(1) #Get sheet 1 in writeable copy
# write_sheet1.write(1, 11, self.invoice.text) #Write 'test' to cell (1, 11)

# write_sheet2 = write_book.get_sheet(2) #Get sheet 2 in writeable copy
# write_sheet2.write(3, 14, '135') #Write '135' to cell (3, 14)

# write_book.save("New/File/Path") #Save the newly written copy. Enter the same as the old path to write over
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the `For` text but there is no object called "for" inside `TOPRIGHTINVOICE`. So that's where your erros are coming from. You can simply change it to:

```py
class TOPRIGHTINVOICE(Screen):
    invoice = ObjectProperty(None)
    purpose = ObjectProperty(None)

    def next(self):
        db.add_loadinfo(self.invoice.text, self.purpose.text)
        
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "CARRIERPAGE"

    def reset(self):
        self.invoice.text = ""
        self.purpose.text = ""

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "CARRIERPAGE"
...
```

And it will work.

But i have to say that you don't need to create a new object for every text input. This can take up memory and lead to confusions like that one. You're already passing an `id` to the input, so lets use it:

First delete this:

```py
    invoice = ObjectProperty(None)
    purpose = ObjectProperty(None)
```

And also this on your kv file:

```
    invoice: invoice
    purpose: purpose
```

And then you can just use `self.ids.yourID` to referenciate the object. Like that:

```py
    def next(self):
        db.add_loadinfo(self.ids.invoice.text, self.ids.purpose.text)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, however, I think I am now getting more errors.                         Code: https://hastebin.com/zasiriwiji.py                                                                                                 Errors: https://hastebin.com/teyakijutu.kotlin                                                                             Lastly, how do you recommend I organize text imputs so I am not creating new objects for every input?

Comment: Looks like these errors are coming from your `DataBase` class, on the method `load()`.  On line `ids.invoice.text, ids.purpose.text, created = line.strip().split(";")` you don't have an element `ids` on this class. The `ids` are an object from the `kivy` class and it will fail if you try to create something like what you are doing there.

Comment: For this class you should just use `invoice` and `purpose`, since these are the variables you're trying to manage.

Comment: okay, but I still get the "too many values to unpack (expected 3)" errors on that same line. How should I resolve this?

Comment: What is the output when you print `line.strip().split(";")` ?

Comment: the output into the text file is invoice;purpose;date created (not literally but their string values), however, it won't print that anymore due to the error crashing the app.

Comment: For what I see you're trying to load even before starting the app, so if your line is blank there won't be three values to unpack and python will throw that error. Try to change the funtion `load` just to see what you have on your line.

Comment: Can you send me the code line you're referring to? And the change you want me to make? Thanks. I also dont know if this is allowed but are we able to add each other on discord? Then post the solution you helped me find?

Comment: Also, you are right. I commented out the `for line in self.file:
            invoice, purpose, created = line.strip().split(";")
            self.users[invoice] = (invoice, purpose, created)` and it ran the app.